# Why is AJAX request response not matching the desired output?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this simple JS file:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "is_complete.php",
  type: "post",
  success: function (data) {
    if(data == 1) {

    }

    alert("ok")
  }
})
```

It alerts `"ok"` only if data is `1` or `0`.

Comment: The alert is outside the `if()` so it will fire each success regardless of what response is

Comment: What _is_ the desired output? Currently, you unconditionally alert `"ok"`, and you have an `if` statement that does nothing.

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: Lets reverse this. Why do you think the alert shouldn't fire if data is 1? There seems to be a fundamental misunderstanding here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why have you placed your `alert` outside the if condition.

try replacing the success function to

```
success: function (data) {
     if(data == 1) {
        alert("ok")
     } else {
       alert("no ok")
     }
   
   }
```

Comment: yes it work. bat why my previuos code not work. pls explain

Comment: every `if` , `else`, `elseif` conditions have scopes between the curly braces `{}` whatever you put inside those, will be executed.

Comment: ohkay i undarstand

Comment: please consider accepting it as the right answer.

Comment: okay Adison Masih

Comment: Also, i suggest you to watch a JavaScript Tutorial On Youtube And Understand The Fundamentals Of JavaScript.

Comment: I now follow these video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KGkiIBTq0y0

Comment: @GyanMasih keep going.